# 1956 AHSME Question 23 on the quotient of an irrational number with a real number

Tags: contest-math, irrational-numbers

I was solving some problems from the American High School Math Exam of 1956 (AHSME) from the Art of Problem Solving Website.

[Question 23](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1956_AHSME_Problems/Problem_23)

---

Problem 23

About the equation $ax^2 - 2x\sqrt {2} + c = 0$, with $a$ and $c$ real constants, we are told that the discriminant is zero. The roots are necessarily:

$\textbf{(A)}\ \text{equal and integral}\qquad \textbf{(B)}\ \text{equal and rational}\qquad \textbf{(C)}\ \text{equal and real} \\ \textbf{(D)}\ \text{equal and irrational} \qquad \textbf{(E)}\ \text{equal and imaginary}$

Solution
Plugging into the quadratic formula, we get

$$
x = \frac{2\sqrt{2} \pm \sqrt{8-4ac}}{2a}.$$

The discriminant is equal to 0, so this simplifies to $x = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{2a}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a}.$ Because we are given that $a$ is real, $x$ is always rational and the answer is $\boxed{\textbf{(B)}}.$

---

The answer confuses me. Is this implying that the quotient of an irrational number and a real number is necessarily a *rational* number? My understanding is that depends on the value of $a$

Comment: As stated, the conclusion is incorrect.  We could have, say, $(a,c)=(1, 2)$  for which the quadratic $x^2-2\sqrt 2\, x +2=(x-\sqrt 2)^2$ has equal, irrational roots.

Comment: A working link is this one but the proposed solution is false.

Comment: Fixed the link. I guess the answer is an error then, but I always try to assume I'm wrong first :)

Comment: A working link is this one but the proposed solution is false.  https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1956_AHSME_Problems/Problem_23

Comment: According to the provided [answer key](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1956_AHSME_Answer_Key), the correct answer is C. So the given proof is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, I would say, badly worded; and the solution that you quote is flat out wrong. I think what the questioners have in mind is that both roots are equal to $\frac{\sqrt 2}{a}$, which is *necessarily* a real number (but could also be integral, rational, or irrational). So the answer is (C).